# how to get the value off parameter from the url string?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, url-parameters

Link : http://yaezde.localhost/machen/mach-den-impfcheck/question=2

i know how to get the whole url by using window.location.href; but after than i want to know what will be the regex to get question paramter value.

answer: var question=2

i have tried this code..but not working for my scenario

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var foo = getParameterByName('question');
```

Comment: function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

Comment: Have you tried the following: [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {//note parameter url
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&\\/](" + name + "=([^&#]*))(?:&|#|$)");
  //                         ^^^ ^ in your example /question=2
        results =regex.exec(url);
  console.log(results);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var url='http://yaezde.localhost/machen/mach-den-impfcheck/question=2'
var foo = getParameterByName('question', url);//include url in arguments or it will be undefined in the function
console.log(foo);

//Another way to access url in the function scope
function getParameterByName(name){
   //get url from global scope if exists
   var url = url || window.location.href;
   //other things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, i would suggest to utilise an existing library like
https://github.com/Mikhus/domurl or [https://medialize.github.io/URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)

The APIs of these libraries should be straightforward to use, and have already been tested.